# Change location of sqlite database using unity

Tags: android, sqlite, unity-game-engine, unityscript

How can I change the location of my sqlite database on unity android. My path that is currently using is :

```
Application.persistentDataPath + "sample.db";
```

I searched other forums where the path locate and it says it is on **"data/data/com.mypackage.package/files/sample.db"**. I want it to move on **"com.mypackage.package/databases/sample.db"**. How can I make it?

Comment: As long as it's in your app's private storage location (anywhere inside `/data/data/<your_package>/` or a subdirectory thereof), does it really matter where it's located?

Comment: Yes. all I want to do is to import it in eclipse. Some codes will be done on eclipse and i want it to connect to existing database which is the sample.db